# Spark: Best practice for retrieving big data from RDD to local machine

Tags: apache-spark

I've got big RDD(1gb) in yarn cluster. On local machine, which use this cluster I have only 512 mb. I'd like to iterate over values in RDD on my local machine. I can't use collect(), because it would create too big array locally which more then my heap. I need some iterative way. There is method iterator(), but it requires some additional information, I can't provide.

**UDP: commited toLocalIterator method**

Comment: toLocalIterator is not ideal if you want to iterate locally over a partition at a time

Comment: @LandonKuhn why not?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update:** `RDD.toLocalIterator` method that appeared after the original answer has been written is a more efficient way to do the job. It uses `runJob` to evaluate only a single partition on each step.

**TL;DR** And the original answer might give a rough idea how it works:

First of all, get the array of partition indexes:

```scala
val parts = rdd.partitions
```

Then create smaller rdds filtering out everything but a single partition. Collect the data from smaller rdds and iterate over values of a single partition:

```scala
for (p <- parts) {
    val idx = p.index
    val partRdd = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(a => if (a._1 == idx) a._2 else Iterator(), true)
    //The second argument is true to avoid rdd reshuffling
    val data = partRdd.collect //data contains all values from a single partition 
                               //in the form of array
    //Now you can do with the data whatever you want: iterate, save to a file, etc.
}
```

I didn't try this code, but it should work. Please write a comment if it won't compile. Of cause, it will work only if the partitions are small enough. If they aren't, you can always increase the number of partitions with `rdd.coalesce(numParts, true)`.

Comment: does this code cause each partition to be computed in serial when it loops through and call mapPartitionsWithIndex? What's the best way to remedy this?

Comment: @Wildfire Will this approach resolve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044231/save-a-spark-rdd-using-mappartition-with-iterator/38046472#38046472). Else how to resolve using any or might be this approach.

Comment: @Wildfire - does it work in parallel across multiple executors? I am looking to perform parallel processing across executors but retrieve the results as list to driver for further processing.

Comment: @Dwarrior Just perform shuffle after expensive computation, i.e.: `rdd.map(....).repartition(10).toLocalIterator`. In this case results will be computed in parallel and then collected sequentially to driver.

Comment: @Wildfire - Can you please check this question and let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Wildfire - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947269/spark-2-x-with-mappartitions-large-number-of-records-parallel-processing

Answer (score 15):

Wildfire answer seems semantically correct, but I'm sure you should be able to be vastly more efficient by using the API of Spark.  If you want to process each partition in turn, I don't see why you can't using `map`/`filter`/`reduce`/`reduceByKey`/`mapPartitions` operations.  The only time you'd want to have everything in one place in one array is when your going to perform a non-monoidal operation - but that doesn't seem to be what you want.  You should be able to do something like:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(recordsIterator => your code that processes a single chunk)
```

Or this

```
rdd.foreachPartition(partition => {
  partition.toArray
  // Your code
})
```

Comment: Is't these operators execute on cluster?

Comment: Yes it will, but why are you avoiding that? If you can process each chunk in turn, you should be able to write the code in such a way so it can distribute - like using `aggregate`.

Comment: Is not the iterator returned by `forEachPartitition` the **data** iterator for a single partition - and not an iterator of all partitions?

Comment: @javadba Yes it is for a single partition.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the same approach as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801828/1296661) by @Wildlife but written in pyspark.

The nice thing about this approach - it lets user access records in RDD in order. I'm using this code to feed data from RDD into STDIN of the machine learning tool's process.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100), 10)
def make_part_filter(index):
    def part_filter(split_index, iterator):
        if split_index == index:
            for el in iterator:
                yield el
    return part_filter

for part_id in range(rdd.getNumPartitions()):
    part_rdd = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(make_part_filter(part_id), True)
    data_from_part_rdd = part_rdd.collect()
    print "partition id: %s elements: %s" % (part_id, data_from_part_rdd)
```

Produces output:

```
partition id: 0 elements: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
partition id: 1 elements: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
partition id: 2 elements: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
partition id: 3 elements: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
partition id: 4 elements: [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
partition id: 5 elements: [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
partition id: 6 elements: [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
partition id: 7 elements: [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
partition id: 8 elements: [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
partition id: 9 elements: [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
```

Answer (score 2):

pyspark dataframe solution using [RDD.toLocalIterator()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator):

```python
separator  = '|'
df_results = hiveCtx.sql(sql)
columns    = df_results.columns
print separator.join(columns)

# Use toLocalIterator() rather than collect(), as this avoids pulling all of the
# data to the driver at one time.  Rather, "the iterator will consume as much memory
# as the largest partition in this RDD."
MAX_BUFFERED_ROW_COUNT = 10000
row_count              = 0
output                 = cStringIO.StringIO()
for record in df_results.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    d = record.asDict()
    output.write(separator.join([str(d[c]) for c in columns]) + '\n')
    row_count += 1
    if row_count % MAX_BUFFERED_ROW_COUNT== 0:
        print output.getvalue().rstrip()
        # it is faster to create a new StringIO rather than clear the existing one
        # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330812/how-do-i-clear-a-stringio-object
        output = cStringIO.StringIO()
if row_count % MAX_BUFFERED_ROW_COUNT:
    print output.getvalue().rstrip()
```

Comment: `toLocalIterator()` is available directly in `DataFrame` (since `2.0.0`).

Answer (score 1):

Map/filter/reduce using Spark and download the results later? I think usual Hadoop approach will work.

Api says that there are map - filter - saveAsFile commands: https://spark.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/scala-programming-guide.html#transformations

Comment: Bad option. I don't want to do serialization/deserialization. So I want this data retrieving from spark

Comment: How do you intend to get 1gb without serde(i.e. storing on the disk.) ? on a node with 512mb ?

Comment: By iterating over the RDD. You should be able to get each partition in sequence to send each data item in sequence to the master, which can then pull them off the network and work on them.

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 1.3.1 , the format is as follows

```
val parts = rdd.partitions
    for (p <- parts) {
        val idx = p.index
        val partRdd = data.mapPartitionsWithIndex { 
           case(index:Int,value:Iterator[(String,String,Float)]) => 
             if (index == idx) value else Iterator()}
        val dataPartitioned = partRdd.collect 
        //Apply further processing on data                      
    }
```