# Writing to HBase via Spark: Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I'm trying to write some simple data in HBase (0.96.0-hadoop2) using Spark 1.0 but I keep getting getting serialization problems. Here is the relevant code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client._
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import java.util.Properties
import java.io.FileInputStream
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put

object PutRawDataIntoHbase{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var propFileName = "hbaseConfig.properties"
    if(args.size > 0){
      propFileName = args(0)
    }

    /** Load properties here **/
   val theData = sc.textFile(prop.getProperty("hbase.input.filename"))
     .map(l => l.split("\t"))
     .map(a => Array("%010d".format(a(9).toInt)+ "-" + a(0) , a(1)))

   val tableName = prop.getProperty("hbase.table.name")
   val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
   hbaseConf.set("hbase.rootdir", prop.getProperty("hbase.rootdir"))
   hbaseConf.addResource(prop.getProperty("hbase.site.xml"))
   val myTable = new HTable(hbaseConf, tableName)
   theData.foreach(a=>{
     var p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(a(0)))
     p.add(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseColFamily), Bytes.toBytes("col"), Bytes.toBytes(a(1)))
      myTable.put(p)
    })
  }
}
```

Running the code results in:

```
Failed to run foreach at putDataIntoHBase.scala:79
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable
```

Replacing the foreach with map doesn't crash but I doesn't write either. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/22594142/1586965

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The class `HBaseConfiguration` represents a pool of connections to HBase servers. Obviously, it can't be serialized and sent to the worker nodes. Since `HTable` uses this pool to communicate with the HBase servers, it can't be serialized too.

Basically, there are three ways to handle this problem:

### Open a connection on each of worker nodes.

Note the use of `foreachPartition` method:

```
val tableName = prop.getProperty("hbase.table.name")
<......>
theData.foreachPartition { iter =>
  val hbaseConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
  <... configure HBase ...>
  val myTable = new HTable(hbaseConf, tableName)
  iter.foreach { a =>
   var p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(a(0)))
   p.add(Bytes.toBytes(hbaseColFamily), Bytes.toBytes("col"), Bytes.toBytes(a(1)))
    myTable.put(p)
  }
}
```

Note that each of worker nodes must have access to HBase servers and must have required jars preinstalled or provided via `ADD_JARS`.

Also note that since the connection pool if opened for each of partitions, it would be a good idea to reduce the number of partitions roughly to the number of worker nodes (with `coalesce` function). It's also possible to share a single `HTable` instance on each of worker nodes, but it's not so trivial.

### Serialize all data to a single box and write it to HBase

It's possible to write all data from an RDD with a single computer, even if it the data doesn't fit to memory. The details are explained in this answer: [Spark: Best practice for retrieving big data from RDD to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698443/spark-best-practice-for-retrieving-big-data-from-rdd-to-local-machine/21801828#21801828)

Of course, it would be slower than distributed writing, but it's simple, doesn't bring painful serialization issues and might be the best approach if the data size is reasonable.

### Use HadoopOutputFormat

It's possible to create a custom HadoopOutputFormat for HBase or use an existing one. I'm not sure if there exists something that fits your needs, but Google should help here.

**P.S.** By the way, the `map` call doesn't crash since it doesn't get evaluated: RDDs aren't evaluated until you invoke a function with side-effects. For example, if you called `theData.map(....).persist`, it would crash too.