# Hbase Serialization error while inserting data from RDD

Tags: scala, google-app-engine, apache-spark, google-cloud-datastore, hbase

I have an issue while trying to insert data into Hbase. I am running the scala code on Google Cloud Spark shell and trying to insert the Data from RDD into Hbase ( BigTable )

Format of hbaseRDD  :-- RDD[(String, Map[String, String])]

String is Row id and the map contains it's corresponding column and it's values.

Code is like this :-

```
val tableName: String = "omniture";

val connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect("*******", "**********")   
val admin = connection.getAdmin();
val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));

TRY 1 : 
  hbaseRDD.foreach{w => 

         val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(w._1));
         var ColumnValue = w._2

         ColumnValue.foreach{x =>       


         put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("u"), Bytes.toBytes(x._1 ), Bytes.toBytes(x._2));

                             }
         table.put(put);

      }      

TRY 2 : 
        hbaseRDD.map{w => 

        val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(w._1));
        var ColumnValue = w._2

        ColumnValue.map{x =>       

        put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("u"), Bytes.toBytes(x._1 ), Bytes.toBytes(x._2));

                             }
         table.put(put);

      }
```

Bellow is the error i am getting :-

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableTable
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableTable, value: BigtableTable{hashCode=0x7d96618, project=cdp-dev-201706-01, instance=cdp-dev-cl-hbase-instance, table=omniture, host=bigtable.googleapis.com})
        - field (class: logic.ingestion.Ingestion$$anonfun$insertTransactionData$1, name: table$1, type: interface org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table)
        - object (class logic.ingestion.Ingestion$$anonfun$insertTransactionData$1, <function1>)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
        ... 27 more
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With reference from  :- [Writing to HBase via Spark: Task not serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250774/writing-to-hbase-via-spark-task-not-serializable)

Bellow is the correct way to do it : -

```
hbaseRDD.foreachPartition {w => 

          val tableName: String = "omniture";

          val connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect("cdp-dev-201706-01", "cdp-dev-cl-hbase-instance")   
          val admin = connection.getAdmin();

          val table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));

          w.foreach {f=> 

            var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(f._1))

            var  ColumnValue = f._2
                 ColumnValue.foreach{x =>       
                      put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("u"), Bytes.toBytes(x._1 ), Bytes.toBytes(x._2));
                                }
             table.put(put);
          }

      }    

        hbaseRDD.collect();
```

Details are well explained in the above link