# Globally sequential access of Apache Spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark, sequential, rdd

I want to implement some sequential algorithm on RDD.

For example:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local[2]").
  setAppName("SequentialSuite")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.
  parallelize(Array(1, 3, 2, 7, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9), 2).
  sortBy(x => x, true)
rdd.foreach(println)
```

I want to see the ordered number on my screen, but it shows unordered integers. The two partitions execute the `println` simultaneously.

How do I make the RDD execute a function globally sequential?

Comment: Partitions are processed in parallel, so why do you explictly set 2 partitions?

Comment: Because I have a large amount of data to process and the code snippet is just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer according to [Spark: Best practice for retrieving big data from RDD to local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698443/spark-best-practice-for-retrieving-big-data-from-rdd-to-local-machine):

```
val rdd : RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(Array(1, 3, 2, 7, 1, 4, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9)).sortBy(x => x, true)
for(p <- rdd.partitions) {
    val partrdd = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i : Int, iter : Iterator[Int]) => if (i == p.index) iter else Iterator(), true)
    partrdd.foreach(println)
}
```