# Is there better way to display entire Spark SQL DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to display the entire Apache Spark SQL DataFrame with the Scala API. I can use the `show()` method:

```
myDataFrame.show(Int.MaxValue)
```

Is there a better way to display an entire DataFrame than using `Int.MaxValue`?

Comment: Try `myDataFrame.show(false)`. Not sure if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: Use RDD.toLocalIterator(), as discussed in this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698443/spark-best-practice-for-retrieving-big-data-from-rdd-to-local-machine

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It is generally not advisable to display an entire DataFrame to stdout, because that means you need to pull the entire DataFrame (all of its values) to the driver (unless `DataFrame` is already local, which you can check with `df.isLocal`).

Unless you know ahead of time that the size of your dataset is sufficiently small so that driver JVM process has enough memory available to accommodate all values, it is not safe to do this. That's why DataFrame API's `show()` by default shows you only the first 20 rows.

You could use the `df.collect` which returns `Array[T]` and then iterate over each line and print it:

```
df.collect.foreach(println)
```

but you lose all formatting implemented in `df.showString(numRows: Int)` (that `show()` internally uses).

So no, I guess there is no better way.

Comment: `df.toJSON.collect.foreach(println)` is better

Comment: but doesn't collect also pull the entire DataFrame to the driver?

Answer (score 5):

One way is using `count()` function to get the total number of records and use `show(rdd.count())` .

Answer (score 4):

Try with,

```
df.show(35, false)
```

It will display 35 rows and 35 column values with full values name.

Answer (score 2):

As others suggested, printing out entire DF is bad idea. However, you can use `df.rdd.foreachPartition(f)` to print out partition-by-partition without flooding driver JVM (y using collect)

Comment: Can you please provide some sample code?  Won't the print statements inside the `f()` function print to the workers' stdout, and not the driver/your shell session's stdout?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/28804763/215945

Answer (score 1):

Nothing more succinct than that, but if you want to avoid the `Int.MaxValue`, then you could use a `collect` and process it, or `foreach`. But, for a tabular format without much manual code, `show` is the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

In `java` I have tried it with two ways.
This is working perfectly for me:

**1.**

```
data.show(SomeNo);
```

**2.**

```
data.foreach(new ForeachFunction<Row>() {
                public void call(Row arg0) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(arg0);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -3):

I've tried **show()** and it seems working sometimes. But sometimes not working, just give it a try:

```
println(df.show())
```