# In "DataFrame API" , how show all rows?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

my code (only example)

```
bikedf.groupBy("Bike #").agg(
    count("Trip ID").alias("number")).\
sort(desc("number")).show()
```

I use jupiter notebook.

In situation, result only showing top 20 rows.

How show Not 20 rows, but all rows?

Comment: I am tempted to close this as duplicate of [Is there better way to display entire Spark SQL DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264373/is-there-better-way-to-display-entire-spark-sql-dataframe/30266712) because if you can show all the rows, then you probably shouldn't be using spark to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Use `collect` instead of `show`:

```
print(bikedf.groupBy("Bike #")
            .agg(count("Trip ID").alias("number")
            .sort(desc("number"))
            .collect())
```

If you want to pretty print, you can do

```
output = bikedf.groupBy("Bike #") \
               .agg(count("Trip ID").alias("number") \
               .sort(desc("number"))
output.show(output.count())
```

Answer (score 0):

You cans et the number of rows you want to show. Also you can set to not truncate the output setting `False` in show function. To show 200 columns:

```
bikedf.groupBy("Bike #").agg(
    count("Trip ID").alias("number")).\
sort(desc("number")).show(200, False)
```