# PySpark: UDF is not executing on a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark in Jupyter on Azure. I am trying to test using a UDF on a dataframe however, the UDF is not executing.

My dataframe is created by:

```py
users = sqlContext.sql("SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM FoodDiaryData")
```

I have confirmed this dataframe is populated with 100 rows. In the next cell I try to execute a simple udf.

```py
def iterateMeals(user):
    print user

users.foreach(iterateMeals)
```

This produces no output. I would have expected each entry in the dataframe to have been printed. However, if I simply try `iterateMeals('test')` it will fire and print 'test'. I also tried using `pyspark.sql.functions`

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def iterateMeals(user):
    print user
f_iterateMeals = udf(iterateMeals,LongType())

users.foreach(f_iterateMeals)
```

When I try this, I receive the following error:

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o461.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
```

Can someone explain where I have went wrong? I will be needing to execute udfs inside the `.foreach` of dataframes for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You won't see an output because `print` is executed on worker nodes and goes to the respective output. See [Why does foreach not bring anything to the driver program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28804647/1560062) for a complete explanation.
2. `foreach` operates on a `RDD` not a `DataFrame`. `UDFs` are not valid in this context.