# LinkedHashMap variable is not accessable out side the foreach loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is my code.

```
var link = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, String]()
var fieldTypeMapRDD = fixedRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, itr) => itr.map(s => (s(8), s(9))))

fieldTypeMapRDD.foreach { i =>
  println(i)
  link.put(i._1, i._2)

}
println(link.size)// here size is zero
```

I want to access link out side loop .Please help.

Comment: Please provide a sample `fixedRDD` so we can try and reproduce the issue

Comment: Yes fieldTypeMapRDD is not empty.FixedRDD is like (clo_name1,type),(colname2,type) in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why your code is not supposed to work:

1. Before your `foreach` task is started, whole your function's closure inside `foreach` block is serialized and sent first to master, then to each of workers. This means each of them will have its own instance of `mutable.LinkedHashMap` as copy of `link`.
2. During `foreach` block each worker will put each of its items inside its own `link` copy
3. After your task is done you have still empty local `link` and several non-empty former copies on each of worker nodes.

Moral is clear: don't use local mutable collections with RDD. It's just not going to work.

One way to get whole collection to local machine is `collect` method.
You can use it as:

```
val link = fieldTypeMapRDD.collect.toMap
```

or in case of need to preserve the order:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
val link = ListMap(fieldTypeMapRDD.collect:_*)
```

But if you are really into `mutable` collections, you can modify your code a bit. Just  change

```
fieldTypeMapRDD.foreach {
```

to

```
fieldTypeMapRDD.toLocalIterator.foreach {
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698443/spark-best-practice-for-retrieving-big-data-from-rdd-to-local-machine).

Comment: Thank you for your response .So how can i put RDD values inside the LinkedHashMap ?

Comment: @user2126135 Give me a minute. I'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you.Let me try this one .I think this tomap will change the order .I dont want to change the order is it possible ?