# Spark Scala Get Data Back from rdd.foreachPartition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, scalikejdbc

I have some code like this:

```
      println("\nBEGIN Last Revs Class: "+ distinctFileGidsRDD.getClass)
      val lastRevs = distinctFileGidsRDD.
        foreachPartition(iter => {
          SetupJDBC(jdbcDriver, jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPassword)
          while(iter.hasNext) {
            val item = iter.next()
            //println(item(0))
            println("String: "+item(0).toString())
            val jsonStr = DB.readOnly { implicit session =>
              sql"SELECT jsonStr FROM lasttail WHERE fileGId = ${item(0)}::varchar".
                map { resultSet => resultSet.string(1) }.single.apply()
            }
            println("\nJSON: "+jsonStr)
          }
        })
      println("\nEND Last Revs Class: "+ lastRevs.getClass)
```

The code outputs (with heavy edits) something like:

```
BEGIN Last Revs Class: class org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
String: 1fqhSXPE3GwrJ6SZzC65gJnBaB5_b7j3pWNSfqzU5FoM
JSON: Some({"Struct":{"fileGid":"1fqhSXPE3GwrJ6SZzC65gJnBaB5_b7j3pWNSfqzU5FoM",... )
String: 1eY2wxoVq17KGMUBzCZZ34J9gSNzF038grf5RP38DUxw
JSON: Some({"Struct":{"fileGid":"1fqhSXPE3GwrJ6SZzC65gJnBaB5_b7j3pWNSfqzU5FoM",... )
...
JSON: None()
END Last Revs Class: void
```

QUESTION 1:
How can I get the lastRevs value to be in a useful format like the JSON string/null or an option like Some / None?

QUESTION 2: 
My preference: IS there another way get at partitions data that an RDD-like format (rather than the iterator format)?

```
dstream.foreachRDD { (rdd, time) =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionIterator =>
    val partitionId = TaskContext.get.partitionId()
    val uniqueId = generateUniqueId(time.milliseconds, partitionId)
    // use this uniqueId to transactionally commit the data in partitionIterator
  } 
}
```

from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#performance-tuning

QUESTION 3: Is the method of getting data that I am using a sane method (given I am following the link above)? (Put aside the fact that this is a scalikejdbc system JDBC right now. This is going to be a key, value store of some type other than this prototype.)

Comment: I don't get the question. `lastRevs` should be `Unit` because `.forEachPartition` is only used for its side effect (the function is T=>Unit). I think you want to transform the data, like using `mapPartitions` instead.  I'd like to understand what is the overal goal here, because the individual questions don't make much sense (to me)

Comment: @maasg: Yes. This is the answer that I am looking for - mapPartitions. I found another example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698443/spark-best-practice-for-retrieving-big-data-from-rdd-to-local-machine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a transformation that uses resources local to the executor (such as a DB or network connection), you should use `rdd.mapPartitions`. It allows to initialize some code locally to the executor and use those local resources to process the data in the partition.

The code should look like:

```
 val lastRevs = distinctFileGidsRDD.
        mapPartitions{iter => 
          SetupJDBC(jdbcDriver, jdbcUrl, jdbcUser, jdbcPassword)
          iter.map{ element => 
            DB.readOnly { implicit session =>
              sql"SELECT jsonStr FROM lasttail WHERE fileGId = ${element(0)}::varchar"
              .map { resultSet => resultSet.string(1) }.single.apply()
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: you mean that it differs from `foreachPartition` in that it uses Executor's resources instead of Driver's resources? Ie. code `foreachPartition` code is executed on Driver whereas `mapPartitions` on Executor ... right?

Comment: @lisak  No,  Both `foreachPartition` and `mapPartitions` will let you run code on the executors. The difference is that `foreachPartition` only does side-effects (like write to a db), while `mapPartitions` returns a value.  The key of this question is 'how to get data back' hence `mapPartitions` is the way to go.

Comment: @maasg     I have a code like this 
   '  
val company_model_vals_df = enriched_company_model_vals_df.repartition(col("model_id"),col("fiscal_quarter"),col("fiscal_year"))   

company_model_vals_df.foreachPartition( 
             writeAsParquet(dataframe) ///will write as parquet in hdfs //// But how to use foreachPartition here ?
    
             )