# spark 2.x with mapPartitions large number of records parallel processing

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I am trying to use spark mapPartitions with Datasets[Spark 2.x] for copying large list of files [1 million records] from one location to another in parallel.
However, at times, I am seeing that one record is getting copied multiple times.

The idea is to split 1 million files into number of partitions (here, 24). Then for each partition, perform copy operation in parallel and finally get result from each partition to perform further actions.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
  def process(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  import spark.implicits._
  //Get source and target List for 1 million records
  val sourceAndTargetList =
    List(("source1" -> "target1"), ("source 1 Million" -> "Target 1 Million"))

  // convert list to dataframe with number of partitions as 24
  val SourceTargetDataSet =
    sourceAndTargetList.toDF.repartition(24).as[(String, String)]
  var dfBuffer = new ListBuffer[DataFrame]()
  dfBuffer += SourceTargetDataSet
    .mapPartitions(partition => {
      println("partition id: " + TaskContext.getPartitionId)
      //for each partition
      val result = partition
        .map(row => {
          val source = row._1
          val target = row._2
          val copyStatus = copyFiles(source, target) // Function to copy files that returns a boolean
          val dataframeRow = (target, copyStatus)
          dataframeRow
        })
        .toList

      result.toIterator
    })
    .toDF()

  val dfList = dfBuffer.toList
  val newDF = dfList.tail.foldLeft(dfList.head)(
    (accDF, newDF) => accDF.join(newDF, Seq("_1"))
  )

  println("newDF Count " + newDF.count)
  newDF
}
```

Update 2: I changed the function as shown below and so far it is giving me consistent results as expected. May I know what I was doing wrong and am I getting the required parallelization using below function? If not, how can this be optimized?

```
def process(spark: SparkSession): DataFrame = {
  import spark.implicits._
  //Get source and target List for 1 miilion records
  val sourceAndTargetList =
    List(("source1" -> "target1"), ("source 1 Million" -> "Target 1 Million"))

  // convert list to dataframe with number of partitions as 24
  val SourceTargetDataSet =
    sourceAndTargetList.toDF.repartition(24).as[(String, String)]
  val iterator = SourceTargetDataSet.toDF
    .mapPartitions(
      (it: Iterator[Row]) =>
        it.toList
          .map(row => {
            println(row)

            val source = row.toString.split(",")(0).drop(1)
            val target = row.toString.split(",")(1).dropRight(1)
            println("source : " + source)
            println("target: " + target)
            val copyStatus = copyFiles() // Function to copy files that returns a boolean
            val dataframeRow = (target, copyStatus)
            dataframeRow
          })
          .iterator
    )
    .toLocalIterator

  val df = y.toList.toDF("targetKey", "copyStatus")
  df
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One should avoid performing write operations in `map` actions because they can be replayed when an executor dies and the same map has to be performed by another executer.
I'd choose `foreach` instead.

Comment: foreach doesnt return any output, hence I opted to go with mappartitions.