# Streaming a generated CSV with Flask

Tags: python, csv, flask, streaming

I have this function for streaming text files:

```
def txt_response(filename, iterator):
    if not filename.endswith('.txt'):
        filename += '.txt'
    filename = filename.format(date=str(datetime.date.today()).replace(' ', '_'))
    response = Response((_.encode('utf-8')+'\r\n' for _ in iterator), mimetype='text/txt')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={filename}'.format(filename=filename)
    return response
```

I am working out how to stream a CSV in a similar manner. [This page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/) gives an example, but I wish to use the CSV module.

I can use `StringIO` and create a fresh "file" and CSV writer for each line, but it seems very inefficient. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to this answer [how do I clear a stringio object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330812/how-do-i-clear-a-stringio-object) it is quicker to just create a new `StringIO` object for each line in the file than the method I use below. However if you still don't want to create new `StringIO` instances you can achieve what you want like this:

```
import csv
import StringIO

from flask import Response


def iter_csv(data):
    line = StringIO.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(line)
    for csv_line in data:
        writer.writerow(csv_line)
        line.seek(0)
        yield line.read()
        line.truncate(0)
        line.seek(0)  # required for Python 3


def csv_response(data):
    response = Response(iter_csv(data), mimetype='text/csv')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'
    return response
```

If you just want to stream back the results as they are created by `csv.writer` you can create a custom object implementing an interface the writer expects.

```
import csv

from flask import Response


class Line(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._line = None
    def write(self, line):
        self._line = line
    def read(self):
        return self._line


def iter_csv(data):
    line = Line()
    writer = csv.writer(line)
    for csv_line in data:
        writer.writerow(csv_line)
        yield line.read()


def csv_response(data):
    response = Response(iter_csv(data), mimetype='text/csv')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'
    return response
```

Comment: Great answer. I also added a `writer.writeheader()` and `yield line.read()`before the for loop to add the headers

Answer (score 3):

A slight improvement to Justin's existing great answer. You can take advantage of the fact that `csv.writerow()` [returns the value returned by the underlying file's `write` call.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow)

```
import csv
from flask import Response

class DummyWriter:
    def write(self, line):
        return line

def iter_csv(data):
    writer = csv.writer(DummyWriter())
    for row in data:
        yield writer.writerow(row)

def csv_response(data):
    response = Response(iter_csv(data), mimetype='text/csv')
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=data.csv'
    return response
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with large amounts of data that you don't want to store in memory then you could use [SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile). This would use StringIO until it reaches a `max_size` after that it will roll over to disk.

However, I would stick with the recommended answer if you just want to stream back the results as they are created.