# How to flush Python IO Stream

Tags: python, iostream

```
import io

string_out = io.StringIO()
string_out.write("hello")
print(string_out.getvalue())

string_out.write("new Hello")
print(string_out.getvalue())
```

```
OutPut1: hello 
OutPut2: hellonew Hello
```

How i can i flush my first input from the stream so the out put of second stream  become just new Hello

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Comment: `string_out.seek(0); string_out.truncate()` would do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the functon `truncate()`. It doesn't delete the stream but resizing it, so giving it a value of 0 should get rid of all the bytes in the stream. You will also need to use `seek()` to change the position of the stream. Same as truncate(), giving it a value of 0 should offset the position to the start of the stream. Good luck!

```
import io

string_out = io.StringIO()
string_out.write("hello")
print(string_out.getvalue())
string_out.seek(0)
string_out.truncate(0)
string_out.write("new Hello")
print(string_out.getvalue())
```

**Update: What's the difference between truncate(0) and truncate()?**

truncate() uses the current default position, while truncate(0) uses the start position. Because you already specified seek(0) **before** truncate(0), the position is swetched to the start of the sentence before truncating. The below examples should clear it up for you.

- Using `seek(10)` and `truncate()`:

[image]

- Using `seek(0)` and `truncate()`:

[image]

Comment: what's the difference between this  string_out.truncate() and this string_out.turncate(0)

Comment: Updated my answer. Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

getvalue get's the entire string, you can do what your looking for by seeking and reading:

```
import io

string_out = io.StringIO()
string_out.write("hello")
string_out.seek(0)
print(string_out.read())
# hello
string_out.write("new Hello")
string_out.seek(0+len("hello"))
print(string_out.read())
# new Hellow
```

Answer (score 0):

create a `new StringIO` rather than truncating and seeking.When you just go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330812/how-do-i-clear-a-stringio-object/4330829) , In Python 3 creating a new Stream instead of reusing a blank stream is `11%` faster and creating a new one instead of reusing a stream with `3KB` data is 5% faster.

Comment: yes it is true but what about the memory that you are wasting.

Comment: The link clearly states "ignoring potential memory concerns", any way we are closing the old stream and creating new stream .

Comment: ok got it, but i have to reuse stream thats why truncate is the best available option for me on google cloud platform.